# Grails Database Migration Plugin using a ton of Memory

Tags: java-8, database-migration, grails-2.4

I'm using the Grails Database Migration plugin (1.4.0) in a Grails 2.4.3 (UPDATE: have upgraded to Grails 2.5.0 and face same memory issues) application with Java JDK 8 Update 45 on Windows 7 64bit. When I changed to Java 8 I know that the PermGen has been removed and replaced with the MetaSpace and the regular Heap. When running my migration (dbm-update), I'm getting an

```
"Error Error executing script DbmUpdate: Java heap space (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)"
```

Why is the database migrations plugin using that much Heap Space? If I downgrade to Grails 2.3.x, the migrations plugin will run the migrations with a lot less memory.

--UPDATE--
Resolved at least updating the database by setting a "GRAILS_OPTS" env var with:

```
-Xms2G -Xms1G
```

Comment: What do your migrations look like?

Comment: I'm not sure if that matters, since everything worked fine with not nearly as much memory needed with Grails 2.3.x (before the 2.4.x upgrade). The migrations files did not change when upgrading Grails.

Comment: "Why is the database migrations plugin using that much Heap Space?" - I would've thought the migration code would be a pretty obvious place to look when trying to answer that question - that's all.

Comment: I would certainly agree with that, and I probably should have updated the question to specify the issues seems to come from the version difference even when the migrations do not change.  But considering this question was asked 10 months ago and a lot of people are converting to Grails 3.0 where Liquibase can be used natively through the Gradle plugin, this is probably a null point now.